# программа работает по разному при запуске

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jtextfield

При запуске программы происходит 3 разновероятных сценария:

1. всё работает нормально - чуть меньше половины случаев
2. всё на панели после создания объекта textField не создаётся (в окне только label) - чуть больше половины случаев
3. панель пустая - редко

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
        frame.setSize(200, 100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");

        panel.add(label);

        JTextField textField = new JTextField();

        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(textField);
    }
}
```

Comment: setVisible перенесите в конец кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде вы сначала создаете JPanel и JFrame и выводите все на экран. Потом вы добавляете элементы на JPanel. По-умолчанию, JPanel никогда не перерисовывает панель после добавления элементов.
Как вариант можно сделать, как уже предложили в комментарии - перенести

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

в конец функции.
Либо можно вызвать:

```
frame.revalidate();
```

что в принципе для вас перерисует JPanel и покажет все элементы.